# How to check internal links in an MS Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a reasonable way to systematically check all the internal links in an MS Word document? I am prepared to do this manually (after noticing that for some reasons, some links stopped working when I edited the document), but how to do that? When I Ctrl click on a link, I can see what it points to, but then what? How can I return to the point where I was?

If I right-click on a link and select Edit Hyperlink, Word generally does not show what the link currently points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a clumsy but useful way: Save the document as web page (compressed or not). Then you can open it in a web browser and click on the links, and the browser’s Back button lets you get back to the point where you were.

I’m still hoping to find a more direct way...

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> .

That way the hyperlinks will be changed to the internal code and can be edited. If you press again <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> the hyperlinks will go back to their normal formatting.